# Android disable text watcher when there are letters

Tags: java, android, android-textwatcher

I need help on my code.

I have an `editText` where the user enters the opening and closing time of the store and there is a `checkbox` with "Close".

The user enters the opening time `09:00` and then with the `Text Watcher` I add a space and a dash and the user enters the closing time `19:00`, so that at the end the time is `09:00 - 19:00`.

For example, if the store is closed on Saturday, the user must click on the `checkbox` and when the `checkbox` is clicked, the `editText` has the text set and it says "Closed".

The problem is that when I use the `Text Watcher`, if the length is equal to 6, it adds the hyphen and then when the user clicks on the checkbox instead of writing "Closed" it says "Closed-".

How can I remove that dash?

There is a condition where the `Text Watcher` turns off when there are only letters in the `editText`.

Does anyone have a solution to my problem, do you have any advice for me?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert__orari);

        lunedi_inizio_uno = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_uno_lunedi_inizio);

        lunediUno = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox_uno_lunedi);

        lunedi_inizio_uno.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    int keyDell;

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                        lunedi_inizio_uno.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
                                    keyDell = 1;
                                int prevL = 0;
                                return false;
                            }
                        });

                        if (keyDell == 0) {
                            int len = lunedi_inizio_uno.getText().length();

                            if(len == 5) {
                                lunedi_inizio_uno.setText(lunedi_inizio_uno.getText() + " ");
                                lunedi_inizio_uno.setSelection(lunedi_inizio_uno.getText().length());
                            }if(len == 6) {
                                lunedi_inizio_uno.setText(lunedi_inizio_uno.getText() + "-");
                                lunedi_inizio_uno.setSelection(lunedi_inizio_uno.getText().length());
                            }if(len == 7) {
                                lunedi_inizio_uno.setText(lunedi_inizio_uno.getText() + " ");
                                lunedi_inizio_uno.setSelection(lunedi_inizio_uno.getText().length());
                            }
                        } else {
                            keyDell = 0;
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                                    }

                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });

                lunediUno.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                                    lunedi_inizio_uno.setText("Chiuso");

                                }


                            }
                        });

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it was enough to add "-" in the length equal to 5 and eliminate the conditions of length equal to 6 and 7.

Comment: You can simply add condition i.e. checkbox.isChecked() then return and skip operation